# Are omeprazole and other members estrogenic and/or antiandrenergic?

Tags: pharmacology, medicinal-chemistry

As of 2020, [omeprazole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omeprazole) is a widely used OTC medicine for various types of acute heartburn and some other gastrointestinal disorders.

Almost every time I read about it I read that one of the possible side effects is [gynecomastia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia), which Wikipedia defines as "noncancerous increase in the size of male breast tissue".

As a non chemist (let alone biochemist), it is unknown to me why should it at least theoretically cause gynecomastia.

Are omeprazole and other (chemical family) members estrogenic and/or antiandrenergic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is not a lot of evidence that the compound itself is estrogenic, but it may affect how estrogen is metabolized in the body, leading to feminizing outcomes.**

Pubmed is a good source for information in the biomedical literature- [here is a pubmed search](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=omeprazole%20gynecomastia) that has more information on those terms.

Looking through some of the results of that search, I find that there seems to be a fair amount of evidence that omeprazole has *something* to do with gynecomastia, but the association is not strong:

- [A review](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1517/14740338.2012.712109?journalCode=ieds20) of the literature has some conflicting information. One study of general practice in Britain suggested no detectable statistical relationship between taking omeprazole and gynecomastia. However, a smaller study suggested that in people who experienced gynecomastia who were also taking omeprazole, removing omeprazole helped in the majority of cases. I suggest reading the section of that review on omeprazole. **The conclusion of the review is that omeprazole *probably* has a role in gynecomastia**.
- There is a literature of studies (mostly in Spain?) ascribing omeprazole a role in gynecomastia. [One example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7771409).
- There is evidence that [omeprazole has a chemical effect on estrogen metabolism](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/bpb/26/5/26_5_695/_pdf/-char/en). However, it was much less strong than some other drugs examined.
- There is evidence that omeprazole slows the metabolism of estradiol, an active estrogen compound (see Figure 2 in the review linked above).

Overall, people seem to say it (and related compounds) probably has something to do with gynecomastia, but it is not a principal contributor *on average*. Possibly it shows a synergy with some other drug or some lifestyle variable.